# Create JSON backslash + slash with Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson, backslash

In Java class there is a field

```
    String cardExpiration = "1022"; //I can format it as needed
```

Using Jackson libray I need to create the following JSON:

```
{
  "cardExpiration":"10\/22"
}
```

I'm using the following code

```
        String cardExpiration = "10\\/22";
        MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo(cardExpiration);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo);
```

This code returns JSON with "10\\/22" (double backslashes, but I need just one backslash).
I can not create in Java String "10\/22", as it is illegal escape character in string literal.
Any idea how to get in JSON **"10\/22"**?

Comment: Your code already does the right thing. The visual representation of `"10\/22"` in your IDE simply is `"10\\/22"`. But it still only contains one actual backslash

Comment: If I print resulting JSON string to console it has two backslashes. I don't think it is visual representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the backslash with a second one to define it as String.

```
String cardExpiration = "10\\/22";
System.out.println(cardExpiration); // prints 10\/22
```

Here a working example that includes the usage of Jackson for serializing your POJO. Note that Jackson escapes the Backslash inside the JSON auto. for you. If you really want to have the JSON value `{"cardExpiration":10\/22}` you can add to the attribute in the POJO the @JsonRawValue annotation.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

App.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String cardExpiration = "10\\/22";
        System.out.println(cardExpiration); // prints 10\/22

        MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo(cardExpiration);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo);
        System.out.println(json); // prints {"cardExpiration":"10\\/22"}
    }
    
}

class MyPojo {
    String cardExpiration;

    public MyPojo(String cardExpiration) {
        this.cardExpiration = cardExpiration;
    }

    public String getCardExpiration() {
        return cardExpiration;
    }

    public void setCardExpiration(String cardExpiration) {
        this.cardExpiration = cardExpiration;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Oliver** What I need is that `System.out.println(json);` would print not a double backslash, but just a single backslash.

Comment: @Vladimir: In that case, the original value you're trying to represent doesn't have a backslash *at all*, and is just "10/22". Why do you need a backslash in the JSON? Forward slashes don't have to be escaped in JSON.

Comment: Vladimir check my edit - go for adding @JsonRawValue to your attribute. Than you get {"cardExpiration":10\/22}

Comment: @Jon Skeet It is a requirement from a client. Financial institutions sometimes have very strange formats.

Comment: @Oliver: Your answer helped, but there is still one minor issue. If I use "@JsonRawValue" then there are no quotes. The goal was to get {"cardExpiration":"10\/22"}